# Exception with cbrestore on mac OS X

Tags: couchbase

I am using Couchbase Server 4.5.1.

I am trying to `cbrestore` a bucket, which has been backed up with `cbbackup` on Ubuntu, and I am getting the following exception:

```
/Applications/Couchbase\ Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/bin/cbrestore . http://localhost:8091 -u Administrator -p st0ryplAyr --bucket-source=storyplayer-api --bucket-destination=storyplayer-api -v -x rehash=1
2017-06-27 09:51:02,610: mt cbrestore...
2017-06-27 09:51:02,610: mt  source : .
2017-06-27 09:51:02,610: mt  sink   : http://localhost:8091
2017-06-27 09:51:02,610: mt  opts   : {'username': '<xxx>', 'verbose': 1, 'extra': {'max_retry': 10.0, 'rehash': 1.0, 'dcp_consumer_queue_length': 1000.0, 'data_only': 0.0, 'uncompress': 0.0, 'nmv_retry': 1.0, 'conflict_resolve': 1.0, 'cbb_max_mb': 100000.0, 'report': 5.0, 'mcd_compatible': 1.0, 'try_xwm': 1.0, 'backoff_cap': 10.0, 'batch_max_bytes': 400000.0, 'report_full': 2000.0, 'flow_control': 1.0, 'batch_max_size': 1000.0, 'seqno': 0.0, 'design_doc_only': 0.0, 'recv_min_bytes': 4096.0}, 'ssl': False, 'threads': 4, 'to_date': None, 'key': None, 'password': '<xxx>', 'id': None, 'bucket_source': 'storyplayer-api', 'silent': False, 'dry_run': False, 'from_date': None, 'bucket_destination': 'storyplayer-api', 'add': False, 'vbucket_list': None}
2017-06-27 09:51:02,615: mt bucket: storyplayer-api
Exception in thread s0:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/lib/python/pump_mc.py", line 91, in run
    rv, batch, need_backoff = self.scatter_gather(mconns, batch)
  File "/Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/lib/python/pump_cb.py", line 72, in scatter_gather
    rv, conn = self.find_conn(mconns, vbucket_id, msgs)
  File "/Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/lib/python/pump_cb.py", line 316, in find_conn
    host_port = serverList[vBucketMap[vbucket_id][0]]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I had the same error (or comparable) previously which is why I am using the option `rehash=1` but this time it does not help.

Any idea about what I could do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little bit late to answer this question, but you have to add "-x rehash=1" to your command:

```
cbrestore ~/backups  http://127.0.0.1:8091  -u Administrator -p password -x rehash=1
```

There reason why is that  Couchbase has 1024 vbuckets on most operational systems, but on Mac there are just 64 vBuckets (for optmization purposes ), so you need to rehash to redistribute the data between all vbuckets